# Creating a register and log in endpoints with Java and Javalin

Tags: java, endpoint, javalin

I'm trying to create endpoints to register and log in with java and javalin. and it has some test cases that I have to pass. So far I've passed 6 out of 7, but I can't get to pass the last test case of the login. Here is what I have for both endpoints:

```
public class SocialMediaController {

    private Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();
   
 private int accountIdCounter = 0; // 
Counter for generating account_id

    public Javalin startAPI() {
        Javalin app = Javalin.create();
        app.post("/register", this::registerHandler);
        app.post("/login", this::loginHandler);

        return app;
    }

   
    private void registerHandler(Context context) {
        Account newAccount = context.bodyAsClass(Account.class);

        if (newAccount.getUsername().isBlank() || newAccount.getPassword().length() < 4) {
            context.status(400).json("");
            return;
        }

       
        if (accounts.containsKey(newAccount.getUsername())) {
            context.status(400).json("");
            return;
        }

       
        int accountId = generateAccountId();
        newAccount.setAccount_id(accountId);

       
        accounts.put(newAccount.getUsername(), newAccount);

    
        context.status(200).json(newAccount);
    }

    private synchronized int generateAccountId() {
        accountIdCounter++; // Increment the counter
        return accountIdCounter;
    }




   private void loginHandler(Context context) {
        Account loginAccount = context.bodyAsClass(Account.class);

        Account matchedAccount = accounts.values().stream()
                .filter(account -> account.getUsername().equals(loginAccount.getUsername())
                        && account.getPassword().equals(loginAccount.getPassword()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        if (matchedAccount != null) {
            context.status(200).json(matchedAccount);
        } else {
            context.status(401).json(""); 
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the last test case that I can't get to pass:

```
@Test
    public void loginSuccessful() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpRequest postRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/login"))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{" +
                        "\"username\": \"testuser1\", " +
                        "\"password\": \"password\" }"))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
        HttpResponse response = webClient.send(postRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        int status = response.statusCode();

        Assert.assertEquals(200, status);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        Account expectedResult = new Account(1, "testuser1", "password");
        Account actualResult = om.readValue(response.body().toString(), Account.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);        

    }
```

Does anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I don't know much about Java

I tried modifying the handlers and modifying the  private int accountIdCounter = 0; to 1 instead of 0 but I was unsuccesful at all my attempts to make it through